# Upgraded to Chrome 6, and now some SSL sites don't load

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

I recently auto-updated my laptop (Macbook Pro with 10.6, it it matters) to Chrome 6. My current employer has an annoying firewall that intercepts all incoming traffic, mainly to filter non-work related sites (eyeroll). The problem is that they do this poorly for https sites.

Now, when I try to load up gmail, I get the following error:

```
SSL connection error.
Error 128 (net::ERR_SSL_UNSAFE_NEGOTIATION): 
The SSL renegotiation extension was missing from the secure handshake.
```

What I suspect is happening is that the browser is trying to go to https://somesite, but hits the internal filter which doesn't handle the 'renegotiation' well, and causes this error. In Chrome 5, it would just give me a warning that something was insecure, but still display the page.

I won't be able to convince any admin to dial it down a notch or fix anything, so how can I turn off or temporarily disable that feature? I know and understand that a nefarious admin could monitor my session, but in this case I'm willing to accept the risk.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from [the Chrome help forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=4cb69b09202ddeaa&hl=en):

> For Chrome 6 stable, renegotiation
>   checks are disabled if you have a
>   proxy configured. We are working with
>   several SSL MITM proxy vendors in the
>   mean time to address this. One of the
>   most common, Blue Coat, have (or will
>   very soon) release an update to their
>   products which includes the needed
>   security fix. Applying this is by far
>   the best solution.
>
> If your proxy is rewriting the TCP
>   streams themselves then there is no
>   way to distinguish this from an
>   attack. In this case, adding
>   --allow-ssl-mitm-proxies to the command line will disable this check
>   and all other additional security
>   measures that we have roadmapped in
>   this area.

You'd have to enable this switch by launching Chrome from the Terminal and the command should read `open /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --allow-ssl-mitm-proxies` (assuming you have Chrome in your **/Applications** folder.

Comment: Makes sense, and it is Blue Coat that is annoying me, but Chrome is telling me that the --allow-ssl-mitm-proxies switch is unrecognized. Chrome is in the /Applications folder. Version: 6.0.472.55

Comment: It may be a Windows-specific switch. Try it on the app itself? `open /Applications/Google Chrome.app --allow-ssl-mitm-proxies`

Comment: I figured it out. The `open` command is what was taking the switch (not chrome). Just executing `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --allow-ssl-mitm-proxies` runs it, though it requires the terminal window to stay open... So I created an AppleScript that wrapped it all up: http://gist.github.com/574049